# Nearest Neighbor 3D w/ Delete & Add Operations

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor

Does there exist nearest neighbor data structure that supports delete and add operations along with exact nearest neighbor queries? Looking for a Python implementation ideally.

**Attempts:**

- Found MANY implementations for approximate nearest neighbor queries in high dimensional spaces.
- Found KD Trees and Ball Trees but they do not allow for dynamic rebalancing.
- Thinking an algorithm could be possible with locality sensitive hashing.
- Looking at OctTrees.

**Context:**

1. For each point of 10,000 points, query for it's nearest neighbor
2. Evaluate each pair of neighbors
3. Pick one and delete the pair of points and add a merged point.
4. Repeat for some number of iterations

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There exists such a datastructure. I invented one. I had exactly this problem at hand. The datastructure makes KD-trees seem excessively complex. It consists of only sorted lists of points in each dimensionality the points have.

Obviously you can add and removing a n-dimensional point from n lists sorted by their respective dimensions rather trivially without issue. A lot of the tricks allows one to iterate these lists and mathematically prove you have the shortest distance to a point. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350215/fastest-nearest-neighbor-algorithm/41532600#41532600) for elaboration and code.

I must note though that your context is wrong. The closest point for A may be B, but it doesn't hold that B's closest point is necessarily A. You could rig a chain of points such that each distance between each link is less than the one before but also necessarily further than the other points resulting in there being only 1 pair of neighbors that share their nearest neighbor.